# Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormControlLike'

Tags: angular, frontend, angular9, angular-ivy

I turned ON Ivy compiler in my project which started in Angular 7 at the beginning and it is now running on Angular 9 and Ivy. So when running `npm run build` I got this errors:

```
Type 'FormGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormControlLike'.
```

The case:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
```

In TypeScript firstFormGroup is defined like this

```
firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the output of `ng version`?

Comment: Angular CLI: 9.0.5
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.5

@angular-devkit/core         9.0.5

@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.5

@schematics/angular          9.0.5

@schematics/update           0.900.5

rxjs